# Map one dataframe to other dataframe (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, combine

I would like to map the values in df1 dataframe to the df2 dataframe.

df:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1001 | john |
| 1002 | amy |
| 1003 | jim |

df2:

| name | salary | department |
| --- | --- | --- |
| john | 2000 | A |
| amy | 3000 | B |
| jim | 4000 | C |
| john | 5000 | D |
| jim | 6000 | E |
| amy | 7000 | F |

Output should be like this ,df3:

| name | id | salary | department |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| john | 1001 | 2000 | A |
| amy | 1002 | 3000 | B |
| jim | 1003 | 4000 | C |
| john | 1001 | 5000 | D |
| jim | 1003 | 6000 | E |
| amy | 1002 | 7000 | F |

Comment: Take a look to [Pandas Merging 101](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53645882/15239951). The answer is `df2.merge(df1, on='name', how='left')`

Comment: It use map when join on one column and returning one column.  Something like `df2['id'] = df2['name'].map(df1.set_index('name')['id'])`  Much faster and more performant that merge.